# Difference between partition key indicated in query expression and feedoptions in cosmos db

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb, database-partitioning, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm calling "queryDocuments(String collectionLink, String query, FeedOptions options)" api in cosmos db for doing some sql query with partition key. I wonder where I should indicate the partition key, query string or feedoptions?

In terms of performance consideration, I wonder if I should indicate partition key in feedoptions options parameter

Like the difference
queryDocuments(collectionLink, "SELECT * FROM root WHERE id = xxx AND partitionkey = XXX", null);
or
feedoptions.setpartitionkey(PK);
queryDocuments(collectionLink, "SELECT * FROM root WHERE id = xxx", feedoptions);

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you indicate partition key in FeedOptions.I did a micro test to observe the performance of both of the solutions.

First One:

```
String name = "A";
FeedResponse<Document> feedResponse = client
      .queryDocuments("dbs/db/colls/part",
                        "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.name ='" + name + "'", null);
System.out.println(feedResponse.getRequestCharge());
```

Second One:

```
FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions();
PartitionKey partitionKey = new PartitionKey("/A");
queryOptions.setPartitionKey(partitionKey);
FeedResponse<Document> feedResponse1 = client
      .queryDocuments("dbs/db/colls/part",
                    "SELECT * FROM c ", queryOptions);
System.out.println(feedResponse1.getRequestCharge());
```

Test Data:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Test shows the second one consumes lower RUs than the first one.My sample data is too small, the gap between them will increase with the increase of the data, I presume.